# adehabitatHS compana test returns lambda = NaN?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm getting bad test results using the R package **adehabitatHS**, and the function `compana()`.

The compana test compares habitat availability with habitat usage by animals. The test performs a compositional analysis, yielding a Wilk's lambda and p-value.

I'm running the test on empirical data (16 animals, 8 habitat categories) that meets the stated format and content requirements of the compana test, but the test returns: `lambda = NaN, p-value = 1.0`.

I've examined my data for the standard causes of NaNs, and I don't see any problems, such as missing values (`NA`s), negative proportions, or row sums > 100 percent. Moreover, the error arises when I use the full data set (16 rows, 8 columns), but not when I use a subset (missing one column). It does not seem to matter which columns are excluded, so long as only 7 or less are included.

Details of my data are below. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Platform: OSX 10.7.4 (Lion)
R Version: R 2.15.1 GUI 1.52 Leopard build 64-bit (6188)

R CODE:

proportions for habitat used (matrix):

```
used.m
    Atr   Cre    DW  Dist  Gra   Mar   Mes   Opn
1   2.76 19.31  4.14 17.24 0.00 28.28  0.00  0.00
2  15.12  1.16  3.49  5.81 2.33 32.56 25.58  3.49
3  57.35 13.24  1.47  0.00 6.62  0.00  8.09 12.50
4  41.18  0.98  2.94  0.00 3.92  0.00 29.41 18.63
5   9.52 17.01 23.13  0.00 0.00 37.41  3.40  0.00
6   2.54 67.01  0.00  0.51 0.51  6.09  3.05  0.00
7  10.45 15.67  5.22  5.97 0.00  0.00 33.58 10.45
8   6.34  0.00  0.00  4.23 0.00  0.00  0.00 21.83
9   0.66 18.54  1.32 39.74 0.00  8.61  2.65  0.66
10 20.75  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00 49.06
11 20.14 18.06 12.50  8.33 0.00  5.56 22.22  9.72
12  0.00  0.00  0.00 58.04 0.00  0.00 13.99  0.00
13 44.23  4.81  0.00  0.00 0.00  0.00 28.85 19.23
14 13.04  2.61  1.74  2.61 0.00 19.13  6.09 25.22
15 35.96  3.51  0.00  2.63 0.00  1.75 25.44  0.88
16  0.00  0.00  0.00 35.14 0.00  7.21  0.00  8.11
```

proportions for habitat available (matrix):

```
avail.m
    Atr   Cre    DW  Dist   Gra   Mar   Mes   Opn
1   1.11 39.18 15.50  0.29  0.00 30.18  4.15  3.43
2  18.96  1.02  0.87  7.40  4.36 37.80  6.17 10.56
3  65.75  3.85  0.57  0.00 12.36  0.00  9.97  3.43
4  20.52  5.44  2.01  0.00  0.08  0.00 10.99 44.22
5  11.16 43.55 10.34  0.00  0.00 18.11  9.60  3.17
6  25.24  9.88  2.77  2.44  4.95 12.90 11.44  2.19
7   5.47 21.13  6.67  0.57  0.00  0.10 30.73  9.59
8   6.23  0.00  0.00  4.85  0.00  0.00  0.00  5.72
9   0.85  1.97  0.09 33.52  0.00  5.58  1.73  0.84
10 18.97  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  5.59
11  0.16 44.41 19.16  3.53  0.00  1.28 21.65  4.13
12  6.67  3.89  0.31 13.63  0.00  0.00 20.56  0.00
13 21.40  2.38  2.66  0.00  0.00  0.00 21.23 46.96
14 42.62  9.36  1.49  3.89  0.43  3.61 20.79  5.80
15 33.32 12.90  4.17  4.09  0.15  3.96 12.32  4.94
16  5.65  0.00  0.00  1.36  0.00  0.59  0.00  9.71
```

load the adehabitatHS package

```
library(adehabitatHS)
```

run the compana test on full data set (all rows, all 8 columns)

```
fulldata.comp <- compana(used.m, avail.m)
```

check result

```
fulldata.comp$test
Lambda      P 
   NaN      1
```

run compana on partial data (all rows, columns 1-7)

```
partdata.comp <- compana(used.m[, 1:7], avail.m[, 1:7])
```

check result

```
partdata.comp$test
   Lambda         P 
 0.3319731 0.6280000
```

Comment: did you ever find the reason behind this? I am having the exact same issue.

Comment: We did eventually find a work-around, but it was so long ago I don't remember what we did. I will search through my files from the project and post the solution if I can find it.

Comment: Thank you @prefectionist. I got around it in the short term by reducing the number of habitat categories (i.e. lumping some together). I suspect part of the issue was having too many categories for too few individuals - the more data-rich models had no problem.

Comment: @Andrew: the way we got around the problem was to use counts (integers) of animal relocations per habitat, instead of proportion of habitat used. Calenge refers to this as third order habitat selection or "design III".

Comment: Actually I think "design III" is something else. The terminology used is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you @prefectionist, I'll give that a try