# adehabitat compana() doesn't work or returns lambda=NaN

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to do the `compositional` analysis of habitat use with the `compana()` function in the **adehabitatHS** package (I use adehabitat because I can't install adehabitatHS).

`Compana()` needs two matrices: one of habitat use and one of avaiable habitat.

When I try to run the function it doesn't work (it never stops), so I have to abort the RStudio session.

I read that one problem could be the `0-values` in some habitat types for some animals in the **'avaiable'** matrix, whereas other animals have positive values for the same habitat. As done by other people, I replaced `0-values` with small values (0,001), ran `compana` and it worked BUT the lambda values returned me `NaN`.

The problem is similar to the one found here

[adehabitatHS compana test returns lambda = NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804994/adehabitaths-compana-test-returns-lambda-nan)

They said they resolved using as 'used' habitat matrix the counts (integers) and not the proportions.

I tried also this approach, but never changed (it freezes when there are `0-values` in the available matrix, or returns `NaN` value for Lambda if I replace 0- values wit small values).

I checked all matrices and they are ok, so I'm getting crazy.

I have 6 animals and 21 habitat types.
Can you resolve this BIG problem?

Answer (score 0):

PARTIALLY SOLVED: Asking to some researchers, they told me that the number of habitats shouldn't be higher than the number of animals.

In fact I merged some habitats in order to have six animals per six habitats and now the function works when I replace 0-values in the 'avaiable' matrix with small values (e.d. 0.001).

Unfortunately this is not what I wanted, because I needed to find values (rankings, Log-ratios, etc..) for each habitat type (originally they were 21).